# How to query a REST API with arrays through interfaces in Angular CLI?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I am working with Angular 7 and I have a REST API that returns this:

```
{"Placa":"MIN123","Certificaciones":[{"Archivo":"KIO","fecha":"12-02-2018","Nombre":1},{"Archivo":"KIO","fecha":"12-02-2018","Nombre":1},{"Archivo":"preventiva","fechai":"06-02-2018","fechav":"12-02-2018","Nombre":2},{"Archivo":"preventiva","fechai":"06-02-2019","fechav":"25-03-2019","Nombre":2}],"Lugares":[{"lugar":"inicio","fecha":"12-02-2018","Direccion":"Cra 99 No.69A 81"},{"lugar":"Fin","fecha":"12-02-2018","Direccion":"Cra 89 No.69A 81"}],"Inconvenientes":[{"lugar":"Fin","fecha":"12-02-2018","Direccion":"Cra 89 No.69A 81","Descripcion":"No reporta"}],"id":"5c7c990de5b1660fb032dc8b"}
```

through the link:  "http://localhost:3000/api/Carros/5c7c990de5b1660fb032dc8b"  my Angular APP I have it like this:

**My service**

```
//data-api.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'; 
import {HttpClient,HttpResponse, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/internal/Observable' ;
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { VehiculoInterface } from '../Modelo/vehiculo-interface';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataAPIService {
    vehiculos: Observable<any>;
    vehiculo: Observable<any>;
    constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

    getVehiculoByID(id: string){
     const url_api = `http://localhost:3000/api/Carros/${id}`;
     this.vehiculo=this.http.get(url_api);
     console.log(this.vehiculo);
     return (this.vehiculo);
    } 
}
```

According to what I have read from interfaces, my interfaces are like this:

**Certifications**

```
//vcertificaciones-interface.ts
export interface vcertificacionesInterface{
    Archivo ?: string;
    fecha ?: string;
    Nombre ?: number;
}
```

**Disadvantages**

```
//vinconvenientes-interface.ts
export interface vinconvenientesInterface{
    lugar ?: string;
    fecha ?: string;
    direccion ?: string;
    Descripcion?:string;
}
```

**Places**

```
//vlugares-interface.ts
export interface vlugaresInterface{
    lugar ?: string;
    fecha ?: string;
    direccion ?: string;
}
```

**Vehicles**

```
//vehiculo-interface.ts
import {vcertificacionesInterface} from "./vcertificaciones-interface";
import {vinconvenientesInterface}from "./vinconvenientes-interface";
import {vlugaresInterface}from "./vlugares-interface";

export interface VehiculoInterface{
    Placa ?: string;
    Estado ?: number;
    Certificaciones ?:vcertificacionesInterface[];
    Inconvenientes ?: vinconvenientesInterface[];
    Lugares ?: vlugaresInterface[];
}
```

and for the moment I want to show it by console, but obviously I'll put it in the HTML. 
Then implement my component like this:

```
//detalles-vehiculos.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataAPIService } from 'src/app/Servicios/data-api.service';
import { ActivatedRoute,Params } from '@angular/router';
import { VehiculoInterface } from 'src/app/Modelo/vehiculo-interface';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-detalles-vehiculos',
  templateUrl: './detalles-vehiculos.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./detalles-vehiculos.component.css']
})
export class DetallesVehiculosComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private dataAPI:DataAPIService,private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
  private vehiculo: VehiculoInterface={
    Placa :'',
    Estado :null,
    Certificaciones:null,
    Inconvenientes:null,
    Lugares:null
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    const vehiculoid=this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.getDetails(vehiculoid);
    console.log(this.vehiculo);
  }

  getDetails(id:string){
    this.dataAPI.getVehiculoByID(id)
      .subscribe(vehiculo => this.vehiculo = vehiculo);
      console.log(this.vehiculo);
  }

}
```

The result is an empty object.
I think, what I have wrong, is how I take it for the component, I was as descriptive as I could with my problem, please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method `getVehiculoByID` is a observable, so when you log `this.vehiculo` it hasn't resolved yet, try to put your `console.log(this.vehiculo)` after the assignment like this :

```js
this.dataAPI.getVehiculoByID(id)
      .subscribe(vehiculo => {
           this.vehiculo = vehiculo;
           console.log(this.vehiculo);
      });
```